# Problem with encoding tuple data with Web3 ABI

Tags: web3.py, uniswap, abi

I am trying to make a swap on Uniswap v3 through the [SwapRouter contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564#code) via the ExactInputSingle function. The ABI states that this function gets **tuple** as the input parameter. How can I encode this data?
When I try to encode input parameters in tuple I get an error:
[image]

[image]

Are there any other methods of creating swap transaction?

Comment: Try to use an array instead.

Comment: @v1bio If You mean to use list instead of tuple, then the same error occurs. Only this phrase changes: `positional argument(s) of type (<class 'list'>,)`

Answer (score -2):

create the contract instance using ethers.js

```
 uniSwapRouterV3 = new ethers.Contract(uniSwapRouterAddress, RouterAbi.abi, ethersProvider.getSigner());
```

create the params object:

```
  const params = {
        tokenIn: address,
        tokenOut: address,
        fee: poolFee,
        recipient: userAddress,
        deadline: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 900,
        amountIn: amountInToWei,
        amountOutMinimum: amountOutMin,  (or just leave it 0)
        sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
    }
```

and than the transaction:

```
const tx = await uniSwapRouterV3.exactInputSingle(params);
```

This is working and will return the sent transaction.
If you want to get the receipt just wait for some confirmations.

```
  const receipt = await tx.wait([confirms = 1]);
```

Comment: OP is using `web3.py` library.. your answer is for `ethers.js`